# How to create an input function that leverage batch_size?

Tags: tensorflow

Calling `predict` function needs 10GB of memory which is not available in my GPU:

```
estimator = tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn, model_dir=model_dir)
probs = estimator.predict(input_fn=lambda: my_input_fn(valid_records))
```

`predict` function has a `batch_size` parameter which is not available when using `input_fn`. It seems that I have two options (let me know if there is another):

1. Replace `input_fn` with `x` parameter and then leverage `batch_size` param. Currently, I don't know how to do it!
2. Modify my input function to return data in different batches. I don't know how to do it too!

Answer (score 0):

Leverage tf.train.batch function to pass data in batches. Don't forget to set `as_iterable=True` when passing your input_fn function to the predict method.